# How to run modprobe for Wi-Fi at login?

Tags: linux, kernel, debian, wifi

I would like to enable my wifi card automatically at the startup every time. 
However, the command below requires sudo. 
I see `Hardware Disabled` at the wireless connection which blocks the internet access through wireless connection without the sudo command. 
There is no permanent solution to this problem, since those drivers are buggy so deprecate that feature from this thread. 
Temporary solution is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2244018) such that I run in Lenovo G50-30

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad-laptop
```

which solves the problem until next shut down. 
The wireless card is disabled in the next startup. 
The command loads some module to Linux kernel. 
I do not understand the origin of the bug.
The command `rfkill list` gives

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I cannot use `cronjob`'s `@reboot` command because it does not run from the cold system as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/244604/25388).

### Unsuccessful modprobe and /etc/init.d/rc.local

One attempt from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/244604/25388). 
Adding `@reboot modprobe -r ideapad-laptop` to your crontab would work, but apparently only works when the machine is rebooted not when it comes up cold.
So do

```
sudo echo '@reboot modprobe -r ideapad-laptop' >> /etc/crontab
```

That will add the line to your cron jobs, but call it at login by adding it in a line to `/etc/init.d/rc.local`.

How can you enable the modprobe -command at login?

Comment: Have you tried creating a cronjob? Or creating a init script to do that?

Comment: For the cronjob you just need to create a cronjob with the root account and not yours. You need to login as root and edit your cronjob file with the command "crontab -e". Otherwise, If you don't want to create a cronjob you can create an init script, init scripts are always using the root account to run so you will not have any trouble.

Comment: Both solutions are descent. I would choose cronjob because its the easiest! Also I would suggest to wait some seconds after the reboot to start the job, so I would choose something like this :`@reboot sleep 10 && modprobe -r ideapad-laptop`

Comment: @VGe0rge Cannot you add this command to some login chain such that you do not run such a command in crontab at specific intervals, but instead only at login.

Comment: You can't do that easily, there is a way but it is really complicated and I dont like it so I want present it here. You can't add the command you want to your login chain because you want it to run as root.

Comment: Cronjob is not a hack it's a really usefull tool used in unix/linux systems.

Comment: @VGe0rge The `cronjob`'s `@reboot` won't work here, since it is only at login as described here http://askubuntu.com/a/244604/25388

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what is the problem. The post don't seem relevant to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is stated in a rather chaotic way, but this is what I understand:

1. You're talking about *enabling* your wireless network adapter using a command that requires root privileges (hence run using `sudo`). The command you're executing actually *removes* a module (see `man modprobe` under the -r option).
2. It was probably suggested that you remove the `ideapad-laptop` module because it is conflicting with another module. That module is disabled, because the defunct `ideapad-laptop` module has priority over it.

You were probably unable to find the answer you were looking for, because you were searching for the wrong terms. You'll want to disable the `ideapad-laptop` module in a process called [blacklisting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules#Blacklisting).

Simply create a new file under `/etc/modprobe.d/` that starts with `.conf`, e.g., `/etc/modprobe.d/disable_deprecated.conf` and add `blacklist ideapad-laptop` to it. This prevents the module from ever loading. You won't have to run the modprobe command anymore.

Comment: Why does the default debian 8.1 installation have the module which is conflicting another module in Lenovo G50-30?

Comment: Laptops are a bit a pain for developers, because many laptops contain specific hardware that are exclusive to those laptops. That means it's hard to develop and test for those devices. I'm sure the Debian didn't put the conflicting module in there on purpose, but you can ask them yourself. It's open source software, so the developers are very accessible and you can even fix the bug yourself and submit it to them! ;) I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: I filed a bug report about the issue and included this thread as a link to them: *Bug#793848: Acknowledgement (base: Conflicting module ideapad-laptop in Lenovo G50-30)*.

Comment: Brilliant! That was the correct thing to do. I whish people did that more often.